# find duplicates of values with range and sum them up with R

Tags: r, duplicates, range

I do have a df with an ID, value1, value2, and value3 whichs looks like this:

```
ID    val1   val2   val3
01   100.5   7.31   1000
02   100.0   7.33    100
03   100.1  10.40    500
04   105.3   7.28    100
05   100.4   7.30    500
```

val1 and val2 have ranges, let's assume the following ranges: val1=0.5 and val=0.1

```
ID     val1        val2       val3
01   100.5±0.5    7.31±0.1    1000
02   100.0±0.5    7.33±0.1    100
03   100.1±0.5   10.40±0.1    500
04   105.3±0.5    7.28±0.1    100
05   100.4 ±0.5   7.30±0.1    500
```

I want to sum-up rows which overlap within their val1 ranges and val2 ranges. Only when those two conditions are true a sum-up of val3 should happen. And in the end the table should only contain only the line with lower ID and the summarized val3. In my example this would be only the case for the first, second, and last line. In addition should all lines stay which don't fulfill both criterias. This is the result I'm looking for:

```
ID    val1   val2   val3
01   100.5   7.31   1600
03   100.1  10.40    500
04   105.3   7.28    100
```

So far I tried to achieve this with the `distinct` function. However, this doesn't take my ranges and summarization into account.

```
sum_up <- distinct(df, val1, val2, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Note that you asked for **both** conditions to be true, and that only occurs in ID 01. However, for your expected output, it looks like you are okay if only the first condition (val1) is true. Can you update your question to clarify?

Comment: does 99.8 (row 3) not overlapp 100 row(2)? or does it only overlap once per row?

Comment: @JakobGepp: You're right 99.8 overlaps with 100.0 from row(2) but it doesn't overlap for val2. I only want to summarize rows which fullfill both of my criteria.

Comment: @BenNorris: I tried to clarify my question, therefore I added row(5) which fulfill both conditions, too. Only lines which meet both criteria should be merged, all other lines should be kept.

Comment: Is it the row with the lowest ID that serves as the reference or is it the most recent row? Say row A overlaps with row B and row B overlaps with Row D, but row A does not overlap with row D. Do you sum these three together because row B is a common link? Or does Row D start a new grouping?

Comment: Always the lowest ID should serves reference. So in your example it's okay that Row D won't be grouped with Row A and Row B.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I've put some more thoughts into this and came up with a more elegant solution  that should work on arbitrarily long dataframes. The solution assumes that the data is already ordered according to the ID.

```
n <- nrow(data)
used <- logical(n)
groups <- numeric(n)
i <- 1

for (j in 1:n) {
  
  if (used[j]) next
  
  indices1 <- abs(val1[j] - val1) <= range1
  indices2 <- abs(val2[j] - val2) <= range2
  indices <- which(indices1 & indices2 & !used)
  
  groups[indices] <- i
  used[indices] <- TRUE
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Here comes a solution but I have to say that I don't like the part when it starts with looping. I guess there is a more elegant solution but for now that should do.

In a first step you want to know which values overlap with regard to their range. So you will use the `outer` function and `abs` to calculate the absolute difference between each value of `val1` and `val2`. This yields two logical matrices that you combine in the next step to get a matrix that contains `TRUE` when the corresponding column and row overlap in both `val1` and `val2`. For instance, a `TRUE` in row 1 and column 2 means that row 1 and 2 in the original dataframe overlap.

So far, it's quite nice but now you have to process this information to get your entire overlap group. This is where I started to fiddle arounda little bit. It would be easier with less helper variables if you would like to combine rows that just need a link as explained in Marcus' comment.

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:5,
  val1 = c(100.5, 100, 100.1, 105.3, 100.4),
  val2 = c(7.31, 7.33, 10.4, 7.28, 7.3),
  val3 = c(1000, 100, 500, 100, 500),
  groups = rep(0, 5)
)

range1 <- .5
range2 <- .1

overlap1 <- abs(outer(data[, "val1"], data[, "val1"], "-")) <= range1
overlap2 <- abs(outer(data[, "val2"], data[, "val2"], "-")) <= range2
overlap_both <- overlap1 & overlap2

result <- list()
ignore <- numeric(ncol(overlap_both))

for (i in 1:ncol(overlap_both)) {
  for(j in i:ncol(overlap_both)) {
    
    # Ignore this index if the element was already combined with a previous
    # element. Otherwise a row in the dataframe would fall in two different
    # groups.
    if (j %in% ignore) {
      next
    }
    
    if (any(overlap_both[, i] & overlap_both[, j])) {
      result[[length(result) + 1]] <- overlap_both[, i] | overlap_both[, j]
      ignore[[j]] <- j
    }
  }
}

result <- unique(result)

for (i in seq_along(result)) {
  data[which(result[[i]]), "groups"] <- i
}
```

Now you can use the additional column for grouping. I hope that your dataframe does not have too many rows though. That would render the solution rather inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I adapted to my code. I get in the end a result table, however as you already feared the data set I'm currently working with has a couple of rows (~3000). Which results in long rendering time... The link which Markus was describing (always link with lowest ID) is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a different solution that is much shorter and probably more expressive and should work an long dataframes as well.